# How can transfer values collected from a modal to a hidden form input outside the modal React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form within a modal and I want to, on `Update Info` button click, take the data from that form and have them in a list as the value on a hidden input that is outside the modal so that I can save the info together with the rest of form inputs. Here's the code I have so far for the modal section, I would really appreciate it if someone would point me to how I can go about this.

```
const modalFormInput = ({id, value}) =>
         <div className='col-sm-3'>
          <Button onClick={handleShow}>
            Edit Personal Info
          </Button>

          <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>EDIT PERSONAL INFO</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
          <Row key={id} className={'form-group'}>
            <FormText model={model}
                            path={path(id, 'name')}
                            label={Official Name}
                            value={value}
                            error={state.nameErrors[id]}
                          
            />
            </Row>
            
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button>
              Update Information
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
```

I used React Docs to do the modal, I'm very new to React so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pass an `onSubmit` prop to the ModalFormInput and have the button invoke it with the new data.

Comment: Thanks @rayhatfield, I just don't know how to implement that in code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what follows is helpful.

I'd need a bit more surrounding context to provide a complete answer (and your example seems to be missing some critical information, e.g. where `handleShow` and `handleClose` come from), but I can try to illuminate a common pattern for this kind of thing.

Summarized: Pass an *event handler* function as a prop and have the component call that function to communicate information back to the parent component.

Here's a contrived example of the basic pattern.

- It renders an input with an `onChange` handler and some text displaying the current value.
- When the user types in the input, the input invokes the handler with an *event* object. (This is built-in behavior)
- The `onNameChange` handler updates the component's state with the value from the event.
- The new value is reflected in the text on the subsequent render. (Updating state triggers a re-render, so this happens automatically.)

```
function SomeComponent () {
  // keep track of the name in state so we can use it for other stuff
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');

  // define a change event handler for the input
  const onNameChange = event => {
    // event.target is the input
    // event.target.value is the new value
    const newValue = event.target.value;

    // update state with the new value
    setName(newValue);
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <input value={name} onChange={onNameChange} />
        <span>Hello, {name}</span> {/* updates as the user types */}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Extending this to more closely resemble your example, SomeComponent could accept an event handling prop of its own to be invoked when a button is clicked:

```
function SomeComponent ({onButtonClick}) { // accepts an 'onButtonClick' prop
  // same as before
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');

  // same as before
  const onNameChange = event => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setName(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name} onChange={onNameChange} />

      {/* call the handler with the current value of name */}
      <button onClick={() => onButtonClick(name)}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

With that in place, a different component can now use `SomeComponent` to do something with `name` when the button is clicked:

```
function SomeOtherComponent () {
    const buttonClickHandler = (name) => alert(name); // or whatever

    return (
      <SomeComponent onButtonClick={buttonClickHandler} />
    );
}
```